# Cant connect IOS simulator on IntelliJ

Tags: flutter, dart, ios-simulator, intellij-14

I am a Macbook user.
I am trying to use Intellij to edit my Flutter code. My IOS simulator failed to connect after I downloaded a code from an Android user to my Intellij and trying to edit it on my computer.
Are there any ways to fix it?
Thanks.

Comment: Please add more details, like error messages or config you did.

Comment: 'import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Welcome to Flutter',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Welcome to Flutter'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Text('Hello World'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
} '

 https://whychristy.imgur.com/all/?third_party=1
Android appeared under module: https://imgur.com/WlibOwt

Thanks!

Comment: try to use the command 'flutter doctor' and check that everything is correct ?

Comment: Try running the following two command.

`sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`

`sudo xcodebuild -runFirstLaunch`